# calling jquery on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to call a jquery onclick of a hyperlink. but now the dialog appears everytimes of page load. I use the jquery example from this  [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

```
$(function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            width:500,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    autoGeneration();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Overwrite?">    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Will be overwrite. continue?</p> </div>

<a href="#" id="dialog-confirm" class="bigButton">AUTO GENERATION</a>
```

I want to call from on click of the below a link and avoid calling the dialog everytime onload of the page.

Thanks you everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the dialog's autoOpten option to false:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
         //other options
    });
});
```

Change the id of the link so that it is different than that of the dialog div:

```
<a href="#" id="openDialog" class="bigButton">AUTO GENERATION</a>
```

And then just call `open` on the dialog:

```
$("#openDialog").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: I tried like ur code. but when I click the link, dialog doesn't appear.

Comment: @PTY, Did you copy/paste my code literally? If so, I had a typo on it: I had an extra comma after: `autoOpen: false,`. If you don't pass any other options to the dialog remove the comma after `false` and it should work.

Comment: yah.. I forgot to include <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"/>"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"/>"></SCRIPT> . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
        $( "#dialog-box" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            width:500,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    autoGeneration();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-box" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });

    });
```

You need different ID's for the "link" and the "dialog" so changed dialog-confirm to dialog-box

```
<div id="dialog-box" title="Overwrite?">    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Will be overwrite. continue?</p> </div>

<a href="#" id="dialog-confirm" class="bigButton">AUTO GENERATION</a>
```

Comment: plus one. Thanks for explaining in details.

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the `autoOpen` property of the dialog to `false` to stop it opening on page load.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width:500,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Confirm": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                autoGeneration();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Then open it in the click handler of the link:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
    var dialog = $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width:500,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Confirm": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                autoGeneration();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
  });
```

and

```
$('a.bigButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    dialog.dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: when I tried like above, seem like the text in div tag appears on the page.

Comment: @PTY yes of course, the div mustbe hidden , just set style="display:none" on it